# Failed to exec start script: expo start

Tags: react-native, expo

So I have installed Node js 12.14.0 and I tried command Expo start after initiating my project but an error appeared.
I checked the log file and that what's in it, even though it was working yesterday.

```
     0 info it worked if it ends with ok
    1 verbose cli [
    1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
    1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
    1 verbose cli   'start'
    1 verbose cli ]
    2 info using npm@6.13.4
    3 info using node@v12.14.0
    4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
    5 info lifecycle @~prestart: @
    6 info lifecycle @~start: @
    7 verbose lifecycle @~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
    8 verbose lifecycle @~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Windows\System32\new-project\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\Merna Othman\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Merna Othman\.windows-build-tools\python27\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Merna Othman\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\windows-build-tools\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\Merna Othman\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\Merna Othman\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Merna Othman\AppData\Roaming\npm
    9 verbose lifecycle @~start: CWD: C:\Windows\System32\new-project
    10 silly lifecycle @~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'expo start' ]
    11 silly lifecycle @~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
    12 info lifecycle @~start: Failed to exec start script
    13 verbose stack Error: @ start: `expo start`
    13 verbose stack Exit status 1
    13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
    13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:210:5)
    13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
    13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
    13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
    13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
    14 verbose pkgid @
    15 verbose cwd C:\Windows\System32\new-project
    16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
    17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
    18 verbose node v12.14.0
    19 verbose npm  v6.13.4
    20 error code ELIFECYCLE
    21 error errno 1
    22 error @ start: `expo start`
    22 error Exit status 1
    23 error Failed at the @ start script.
    23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
    24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Cannot tell why, but I have the same problem on Windows 10. Works on my MacBook though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be an issue with Node. Works with Node 12.10, but at least not with Node 12.12 and 12.14. See https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/1147.

I downgraded to Node 12.10 and the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. I attempted to just make sure my npm was up-to-date using `npm install npm@latest -g` from command-line and now the expo issue resolved.